# Is it possible to assign select values to variables in sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I assign a selected value to a variable so that I can reuse the value in a nested sql? For example, I may have something that looks like this:

```
select count(user_id), substr(name, 0, 5)
from users
group by substr(name, 5);
```

But in this case, the `substr` value in the select clause may be inconsistent with the `substr` value in the group by clause. It will be good if I can assign one of the `substr` value to a variable and reuse it. This will ensure that the values are consistent. How can I achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: you should go for Procedural Language (PL / SQL) where you can store each and every column values

Comment: I'm trying to avoid PL/SQL in my case. It will be best if I can achieve this using just SQL statements.

Comment: what is your Input data & expected result ? because there is no inconsistency in your query

Comment: in SQLDeveloper, I get a warning that they may be inconsistency. And I do see that I'm repeating the substr in my statement and I wonder how I can clean it up.

Comment: Maybe because the substrings are different?

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow them to be inconsistent, in terms of what they represent - they can be expressed slightly differently, but only in a quite limited way. If your real case is more complicated and you're trying to avoid duplication you could use a subquery and an alias, but seems like overkill in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the duplication of terms in the select list and `group by` clause, you could use a subquery:

```
select count(user_id), name_alias
from (
  select user_id, substr(name, 0, 5) as name_alias
  from users
)
group by name_alias;
```

It seems like overkill in this simple example, but it can be useful with complicated case statements etc. where it saves some work keeping the code consistent; though Oracle would complain if you made a mistake.

You need the subquery because Oracle [doesn't allow you to use column aliases in the same level of query, except in the `order by`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries002.htm#sthref2214), because of how the query is constructed internally.

Comment: @logan - [MySQL does](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html); no idea about Teradata. But the question is about Oracle RDBMS, so not sure that's relevant really.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to assign variables, you need to switch to PL/SQL, since you're saying you try to avoid that, then there's no variables in regular querying,unless you wish to involve server side code.

if you wish to deal with the result as a column instead you could do something like:

```
select count(t.user_id),t.name
from(
     select user_id,substr(name,0,5) name
     from users
) t
group by t.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with alias; Other operations such as calling in sub query is costly operation

In oracle,

```
select count(a.user_id), a.name from (
    select user_id, substr(name, 0, 5) name
    from users) a
    group by a.name;
```

In Many other Major Databases, try with alias which is faster !

```
select count(user_id), substr(name, 0, 5) name
from users
group by name;
```

Comment: Oracle does not allow this, you can only use the alias in the `order by` clause. This will be trying to group by the full name, not the substring, so it will get a 'not a group-by expression' error.